# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, field-theory

I want to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$. In my understanding, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\{a\sqrt{2}+b\sqrt{3}+c:a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q} \}$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\{a(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})+b):a,b\in\mathbb{Q} \}=\{a\sqrt{2}+a\sqrt{3}+b:a,b\in\mathbb{Q} \}$. Bu the two sets are actually different. I suspect that I'm not completely getting the notation. Also, I read that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$, but my interpretation of notation assumes that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. Moreover, I don't see why $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$. Isn't it the case that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})=\{a+b\sqrt[3]{2}\}$?

**Update**: I suspect that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, so this is probably why its index is $3$. But anyway, $\sqrt[3]2$ is not transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ refers to all rational functions that can be written in terms of $\alpha$: it contains things like $\frac{3\alpha^2+1}{\alpha^5+17}$, for example.

Comment: $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ is *definitely* not trascendental over $\Bbb Q$. It's index over $\Bbb Q$ is actually $4$ and *thus*, since it has a finite index, it is algebraic.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli How do you check that? One would need to come up with a polynomial whose solution is $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @Misha So how do you write $  \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ in this form? Would it look like $\frac{f(\sqrt2)+f(\sqrt{3})}{g(\sqrt2)+g(\sqrt3)}$? I'm still not so sure how to "guess" what this notation exactly means.

Comment: The high-level idea is that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt3)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q$, $\sqrt 2$, and $\sqrt 3$. So you can keep doing any operations that exist in a field, and the result should continue to be an element of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt3)$.

Comment: The trick is $a = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, $\ \frac{1}{a} = \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$, $\ \frac12(a+\frac{1}{a}) = \sqrt{3}$

Comment: @sequence $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is a solution of $x^4-10x^2+1=0$

Comment: And  $a$ is a root of $P(x) = x^4-10x^2+1$ irreducible so that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(P(x))$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}] =[\mathbb{Q}[x]/(P(x)):\mathbb{Q}] = deg(P) = 4$

Comment: @quintopia It is interesting that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}$ is also a zero of this polynomial.

Comment: @user1952009 I need to use the Tower Theorem to prove that (without using the minimal polynomial). So I think that what applies here is that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]$. It is clear that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$, but I have no idea how to find that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=2$. Because we know that the basis set for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has dimension 2, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ also seems to have dimension 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the definition of a field extension.

Given a field $K$, the extension $K(\alpha)$ is the smallest field containing K and $\alpha$.

To illustrate, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)= \{a + b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3 + d\sqrt6  \mid a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ as $\sqrt2\sqrt3 = \sqrt6$ (so that the field is closed). (Remember the definition of $[K(\alpha):K]$ is the dimension of $K(\alpha)$ as a vector space over $K$).

I guess the above should answer why $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3):\mathbb Q] = 4$ and $ [\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb Q] = 3$ as $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \{ a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4} \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Going back to the original question:

From the above it should be clear (noting that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ is a field)  that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3) \subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$

As for the reverse inclusion notice that $(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)^2 = 5 + 2 \sqrt{6}$

so we get $\sqrt{6} \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$. (again all I am using is closure)

Furthermore, $\sqrt{6}(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3) - 2(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3) = \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$, implying $\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$.

Hence $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$

Comment: Yes, this is now beginning to make sense! But how can this concept be applied in order to see that $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{Q}]$ is infinite? Is this because we need to extend $\mathbb{Q}$ by $i$ and then also by all the irrational numbers? But then $[\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q}]$ must also be infinite, correct?

Comment: Both are infinite. The best way, in my opinion, to see it is to note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable while the others are uncountable. So the $\mathbb{Q}$ basis must contain uncountably many elements.

Comment: @sequence if $[\Bbb{R}:\Bbb{Q}]$ were finite, then $\Bbb{R}$ would be equipotent to $\Bbb{Q}^n$ for some $n\in \Bbb{N}$, and thus $\Bbb{R}$ would be countable, which is false.  And because $[\Bbb{R}:\Bbb{Q}]\le [\Bbb{C}:\Bbb{Q}]$, then $[\Bbb{C}:\Bbb{Q}]$ is also infinite.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if anyone is still active on this thread but I was just looking at similar examples and wondering if we had $\ ℚ(i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ how would this change the extension?