# Irreducible polynomials of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratics, irreducible-polynomials

Could someone please verify the answers for me? Or let me know how to compute these correctly?

Question: Determine the irreducible polynomials of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{15})$.

Take $\alpha = \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$, I got that $\alpha$ satisfies $x^4 - 16x^2 + 4 = 0$.

So for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)$, we get that  $x^4 - 16x^2 + 4$ should be the irreducible polynomial because $\sqrt {15} = \sqrt{5}\cdot\sqrt{3}$ is not in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ (espepcially since $\sqrt3$ not in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$.

For $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{15})$: We can reduce the polynomial to $(x-(\sqrt5+\sqrt3))^2\cdot (x+(\sqrt5+\sqrt3))^2$ and this will be the irreducible polynomial because these are the linear factors and cannot be further reduced.

Thank you in advance for your comments.

Comment: Do you happen to know any Galois theory?  In this post, I discuss some Galois-theoretic methods for finding the minimal polynomial of a given algebraic number.  Sometimes, expanding the polynomial from linear factors can be prohibitively difficult, but you can at least verify the *degree* of the minimal polynomial as a check for this sort of work: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221706/simple-extension-of-mathbbq-sqrt42-i/2221711#2221711

Comment: @KajHansen My professor covered a little bit in lecture. This question I just posted was from my final exam, which I thought I got all four of them right (I asked about two of those in here). I only got two of them right. I used the method professor expected us to use in the assignment (I mastered the question in the assignment)...

Comment: Right now, other than wanting to learn the different ways to solve this question, I am more curious about the actual solutions because I am gonna petition for it... If he expected us to use Galois theory, I would be disappointed because he admitted that he didn't speak enough about that topic...

Comment: No problem at all @Wilson ; I figured that Galois theory might be more machinery than what's expected of you.  But it does give some nice "check-your-work" tools that you might find useful sometime down the road if you delve further into abstract algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Let $L=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$ (ask, if you don't know how to show that these two fields are equal). Then the fields $K_1=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ and $K_2=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$ are quadratic subfields of $L$. This implies that
$$
[L:K_1]=\frac{[L:\Bbb{Q}]}{[K_1:\Bbb{Q}]}=2,
$$
and similarly
$$
[L:K_2].
$$
As $L=K_1(\alpha)=K_2(\alpha)$ you can tell without any calculations that the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ over either $K_1$ or $K_2$ are quadratic.

---

This is also easy to see directly:

- Show that $\alpha^2\in K_2$ to find a quadratic polynomial with coefficients in $K_2$ that has $\alpha$ as a zero.
- Use the fact that $(\alpha-\sqrt5)^2=3$ to find a quadratic polynomial with coefficients in $K_1$ that has $\alpha$ as a zero.

> The answers are: $x^2-8-2\sqrt{15}\in K_2[x]$ and $x^2-2\sqrt5x+2\in K_1[x]$.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki! But this is the general reasoning and general answer as to what kind of minimal polynomial we can expect though. How would you compute the actual minimal polynomials? In particular, you said that the minimal polynomials over Q(sqrt(15)) is quadratic, does that mean the solution I provided is correct? Thank you!

Comment: No, the minimal polynomials are quadratic, and you gave degree four polynomials, so they cannot be correct. That's why I started out by figuring out the degrees. Always nice to know what to look for.

Comment: Okay. What are your thoughts on Q(sqrt(10))?

Comment: I got x^4 - 16x^2 + 4 as the irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ you have the same quartic you had over $\Bbb{Q}$. None of its factors have coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$. Proving that $\sqrt{10}\notin L$ may be easiest to do with Galois theory, so it is a bit more challenging to justify the calculation I did above.